# How to run one part of tensorflow graph with one input and running the other graph in a loop with multiple inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Having tensorflow graph with two inputs, one part of the graph is processing the first input x and the other part is processing the second input y together with the result of the first part.

I would like to reuse the result of first part of the graph for further runs on the second part, something similar to the code below using partial_run:

```
h = sess.partial_run_setup([first_part, second_part], [x, y])
sess.partial_run(h, first_part, feed_dict={x: x_val)
for y_val in y_array:
        sess.partial_run(h, second_part, feed_dict={y: y_val)
```

The above code require to partial_run_setup again for further partial runs after the executing second_part.